# How to make a proxy object with typing as underlying object in python

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-typing

I have a proxy class with an underlying object. I wish to pass the proxy object to a function that expects and underlying object type. How do I make the proxy typing match the underlying object?

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.obj, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.obj, name, value)

def foo(bar: MyClass):
    ...

foo(Proxy(MyClass())) # Warning: expected 'MyClass', got 'Proxy' instead
```

Comment: You can tweak bases: `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING: base = MyClass; else: base = object` and then `class Proxy(base):...`. Type checker will think that `Proxy` is subclass of `MyClass` and runtime will not be affected.

Comment: where should the if be placed at?

Comment: Before class definition: first define `base` being `MyClass` for `mypy` and `object` for runtime and then subclass `base`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to @SUTerliakov for actually providing the essence of this answer in the comment on the question. The code should look something along the lines of the following:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from my_module import MyClass

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    base = MyClass
else:
    base = object


class Proxy(base):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.obj, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.obj, name, value)


def foo(bar: MyClass):
    ...

foo(Proxy(MyClass())) # Works!
```

Note that your class may not always be available - but that's no real problem. The trick works perfectly fine with TypeVars.

```py
# proxy.py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, TypeVar


Proxied = TypeVar('Proxied')
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    base = Proxied
else:
    base = object


class Proxy(base):
    def __init__(self, obj: Proxied):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.obj, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.obj, name, value)
```

And in the file where you use it:

```py
from proxy import Proxy


def foo(bar: MyClass):
    ...

foo(Proxy(MyClass())) # Works!
```

Comment: For the `TypeVar` example, pyright gives me this: `Expected type expression but received "TypeVar"`

Comment: Hmm, maybe it should be `base = Generic[Proxied]`?

Comment: Generic doesn't work here, I tried that before I used the superclass idea. It'd have been neater. Or at least, didn't work for me. I'm not familiar with pyright, but pylint and flake8 passed for me, and pycharm (my IDE) gives proper inspection with the exact code here.

Comment: The first one works well, but mypy generates a lot of errors in the second case:
```shell
proxy.py:9: error: Type variable "proxy.Proxied" is invalid as target for type alias
proxy.py:14: error: Variable "proxy.base" is not valid as a type
proxy.py:14: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
proxy.py:14: error: Invalid base class "base"
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Looks like we need new annotations in Python, e.g. `InterfaceOf[Type]`

Comment: LInked URL there says "Type aliases can’t be defined conditionally", which sounds like a mypy failure/problem. Pycharm has absolutely no issue with it. Especially since we're using TYPE_CHECKING, which linters should explicitely consider to be True always.